# I want to know what Orion's Federation feature is

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I want to know what Orion's Federation feature is.

I have read the Orion documentation and tried the federation function, and the data was registered in all three Orions.

I thought that the second Orion acts as a Proxy and does not store data, but is that not the case?
If all three Orions store data, is it correct to say that the Federation does not have its own function, but is a concatenation of Subscriptions?

Answer (score 2):

The Federation mechanism you refer is the one on the [documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/federation/index.html). In this case, it is based on subscriptions that copy the data among the brokers on entities changes.

Orion also has the [registration and request forwarding mechanism](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/context_providers/index.html). This case, once the register is done, the Context Broker forward the requests to the one registered. This approach sounds closer to the one you are describing but I encourage you to use the first method (based on subscriptions) since all the advanced operations like filtering are working without issues.

Comment: mapedraza

Thank you for your answer, so if I want to use Orion as a proxy, I can use the "registration and request forwarding mechanism. I understand now. I'll try it.
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A well-designed Federation should not allow value shadowing by a local database. Unfortunately, that's not a feature offered by design by the Orion Broker. That is up to your design and nothing prevents the shadowing, as far as I understand i.e. even you have registered a provider for an Entity, someone can create locally such an Entity, which may be a mess and a source of conflict.

An alternative that may work  is to perform the Federation by a REST Service custom built by you that just acts as a proxy against different Orion Brokers. If this custom service is a single entry point you could guarantee a pure Federated system with no shadowing of values.

Comment: Yes, shadowing is a problem, but, just be careful and you'll be fine. Know also that only updates are forwarded. Creation and Deletion of entities/attributes stay locally and are not forwarded to the federated broker (the one with a matching registration). This is all true for Orion. Orion-LD will implement a very different forwarding mechanism, but, this is still under discussion in ETSI ISG CIM and it might take a year or so until it is fully implemented.

Comment: Jose Manuel Cantera

Thanks for the answer.
I guess I should interpret the federation as a design example rather than a feature provided by Orion. I understand now. Thank you very much.

Comment: kzangeli 

Thanks for the answer, and thanks for letting me know about OrionLD.
Do you have any idea what "a very different forwarding mechanism" will be?

Do you mean the "smart federation" feature in the roadmap?
Or are you referring to SPEC's "Federated Architecture"?